# Angular Restangular Local Storage Interceptor Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I am using a RestangularProvider to set an $http interceptor to inject an authentication header into all restangular requests. The problem is that you cannot inject services into app.config(), so I cannot access the angular local storage I am using to store the token after I get it from the login server.

```
angular.module('app').config(function(RestangularProvider, localStorageService) {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/api/');

    RestangularProvider.setFullRequestInterceptor(function(element, operation, route, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {
       var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');//ERROR:localStorageService doesn't exist
        };
});
```

"authorizationData" is my authentication token stored locally.
As you can see, I need to be able to use the Restangular provider AND local storage. I would appreciate any workarounds. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't inject service into angular configuration `.config` phase. Only providers/constant are accessible into the config phase(Providers are meant for configurable service)

To solve your problem, either transfor `localStorageService` to provider instead of `service/factory`, and then inject it to config block like `localStorageProvider`.

Other way around to achieve it is, you could use `$injector` to retrieve the instance of `localStorageService`. For this you need to inject `$injector` and then use var

```
localStorageService = $injector.get('localStorageService');
```

for getting instance of `localStorageService`